# How do I add a watermark to Cognos report with user id and user login time?

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

How do  I add a watermark to Cognos report  with  user id  and user login time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about adding a [watermark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watermark), but you could add that information to the page (I would use the footer) using some of the many macro functions and parameters available on the Macros tab of the Data Item Expression dialog.

I am using an Active Directory namespace, so I would add user id with:

```
#sq($account.personalInfo.userName)#
```

To add the session start time, you'll probably need the Audit database working.  I would create a query that results in SQL that looks like:

```
select l.COGIPF_LOCALTIMESTAMP

from COGIPF_USERLOGON l

where l.COGIPF_LOGON_OPERATION = 'Logon'
  and l.COGIPF_SESSIONID = 'F14BADE9BABDB106F4A8ACEC7962D7F4B4002E012F1FFA312A7D86E533D5E21A'
```

The sessionID returned by the macro will include additional information at the beginning.  You may be able to get away with a filter that looks like this:

```
[Audit].[User Logins].[Session ID] = substring(#sq($sessionID)#, 5, 64)
```

But there may not always be exactly 4 leading characters and the session ID may not always be exactly 64 characters.  You'll need to test.

Comment: Could you show me  how  to  do " Macros tab of the Data Item Expression dialog"  It's  very difficult to image how to do it without  a  screen capture picture.

Comment: Thank you .  [TWO  HOURS LATER](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QEB38D0pu4)  I did some thing like what you said. [watermark](https://imgur.com/6bayVqW)

Comment: The result I want  is  like this [WATERMARK](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/sampleriskassessmentreportfordccsafetystudents-191105121912/95/sample-risk-assessment-report-for-dcc-safety-students-6-638.jpg?cb=1572956426)

How to do it in cognos ?

Comment: You can create a watermark by using a background image, but I don't see a way to create one using custom text.  The Data Item Expression dialog is displayed when you drop a Query Calculation onto your page.  You're asking questions about such advanced features, I didn't realize you don't know the basics of developing reports in Cognos.

Comment: I supposed you could develop a Custom Control to make a watermark from text.  You'll need to know more about how Cognos works, and you'll need to know about JavaScript and asynchronous module definition (See IBM's documentation regarding Cognos Scriptable Reports -- https://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/data/sw-library/cognos/mobile/scriptable_reports/index.html)  You'll probably also need to be the Cognos server administrator so you can actually create the scripts in the right place.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is very useful for me. Where can I find  some further information about  "#sq($account.personalInfo.userName)#" .  I'm a  Cognos server administrator. I just touch Cognos two month. Still a lot of things to learn.  :)

Comment: The Data Item Expression dialog includes tabs along the bottom and a Tips box.  The Tips are as helpful (or better than) the documentation on the main docs site site (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.cbi.doc/welcome.html).

Comment: I make a report like this [Watermark](https://imgur.com/6bayVqW) , but another question is when  I schedule a report to a pdf and I'm not in login status, how to change  the "Admin" to a report receiver  name?